# Current Location in Google Maps with swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, currentlocation

I'm trying to display the user's current location on a google map but in the case below, the map doesn't even get displayed. What should I change to fix this?

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //user location stuff
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error" + error.description)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
        longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 8)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = center
    marker.title = "Current Location"
    marker.snippet = "XXX"
    marker.map = mapView

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: try self.view.addsubview(mapView)

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't work @John D

Comment: can you give us your code as object c

Answer (score 9):

You can try this bellow code its working fine

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class SearchMapsViewController: UIViewController,
     UINavigationBarDelegate, GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate, 
     LocateOnTheMap, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate 
{

   @IBOutlet var googleMapsContainerView: UIView!
   var searchResultController: SearchResultsController!
   var resultsArray = [String]()
   var googleMapsView:GMSMapView!
   var gmsFetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher!
   var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {        
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView (frame: self.googleMapsContainerView.frame)
    self.googleMapsView.settings.compassButton = true
    self.googleMapsView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.googleMapsView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)
    searchResultController = SearchResultsController()
    searchResultController.delegate = self
    gmsFetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher()
    gmsFetcher.delegate = self
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) 
{
    print("Error" + error.description)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
{
    let userLocation = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15);
    self.googleMapsView.camera = camera
    self.googleMapsView.myLocationEnabled = true

    let marker = GMSMarker(position: center)

    print("Latitude :- \(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("Longitude :-\(userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)")
    marker.map = self.googleMapsView

    marker.title = "Current Location"
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do requier setting on infoPlist and then try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var your "name of view which show map": GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

  placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
     if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){     
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 500
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()  
  }   
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
    mapView.animate(toViewingAngle: 45)
    mapView.delegate = self  }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     let newLocation = locations.last // find your device location
     mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: newLocation!.coordinate, zoom: 14.0) // show your device location on map
     mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true // show current location button
     var lat = (newLocation?.coordinate.latitude)! // get current location latitude
     var long = (newLocation?.coordinate.longitude)! //get current location longitude

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the mapView's frame to **CGRectZero**. This causes the map to have zero height and zero width, no wonder it does not show!

Try setting it to **CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)** for example, this will give you a map at the left top of the screen with a size of 200 x 200.

*I have never used Swift before, so the syntax might be a little different for `CGRectMake()`*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your creation of the map isn't in your `viewDidLoad` function. You may want to try moving that there and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate properties into the `info.plist`.

You should put make sure you have the NS properties of `locationalwaysusagedescription` and `wheninuseusagedescription` in the information properties list. This allows for the permissions of the current location to be asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
```

import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreLocation

class MapsViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

```
var mapView = GMSMapView()
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let marker = GMSMarker()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mapView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)
    
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
    mapView.animate(toViewingAngle: 45)
    mapView.delegate = self
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let newLocation = locations.last // find your device location
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: newLocation!.coordinate, zoom: 14.0) // show your device location on map
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true // show current location button
    let lat = (newLocation?.coordinate.latitude)! // get current location latitude
    let long = (newLocation?.coordinate.longitude)! //get current location longitude
    
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long)
    marker.map = mapView
    print("Current Lat Long - " ,lat, long )
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    mapView.clear()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        self.marker.position = position
        self.marker.map = mapView
        self.marker.icon = UIImage(named: "default_marker")
        print("New Marker Lat Long - ",coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
    }
}
```

}